# Android. Reddit API, cant reply comment (403 Forbidden)

Tags: android, retrofit2, reddit

I cant reply comment using API.
Same error using `JRAW-Android`.

Im using android library `Retrofit 2.6.2`

```
POST (https://oauth.reddit.com/api/comment)

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

User-Agent: android:com.example.app:v1.0.0 (by /u/bodiart1)

Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

form-url-encoded: api_type=json&thing_id=t1_femh2ge&text=yep
```

Method declaration:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(Api.URL_COMMENT)
suspend fun addComment(
    @Field(Api.QUERY_PARAM_API_TYPE) apiType: String,
    @Field(Api.QUERY_PARAM_THING_ID) thingId: String,
    @Field(Api.QUERY_PARAM_TEXT) text: String
): Any
```